# Most efficient way to return entries with no relationship to another table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm developing a table reservation system, and would like to list all Restaurants that have not received any Reservation yet.

I've thought of the following approaches:

- Using `NOT IN()`:

  ```
  SELECT * FROM Restaurant
  WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT restaurantId FROM Reservation);
  ```
- Using `LEFT JOIN`:

  ```
  SELECT rst.* FROM Restaurant rst
  LEFT JOIN Reservation rvn ON rvn.restaurantId = rst.id
  WHERE rvn.id IS NULL;
  ```

I would be favouring the second approach for efficiency.

**Is there a more efficient approach than these two?**

Comment: Run `explain select ...` to see which is faster. Having many restaurants could make the `in` clause slow, but you have to see for yourself. You can also use  `distinct`: `... id NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT restaurantId FROM Reservation)`

Comment: Here is a nice explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query

Comment: 'explain select ...' DOES NOT TELL YOU WHICH IS FASTER it tells you what the opimizer thought was the best way to resolve a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple queries like the one in your example, the query optimizer will be able to resolve  either query with the [same execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/left-join-optimization.html):

> If you use **`LEFT JOIN`** to find rows that do not exist in some table and you have the following test: **`col_name IS NULL`** in the **`WHERE`** part, where **`col_name`** is a column that is declared as **`NOT NULL`**, MySQL stops searching for more rows (for a particular key combination) after it has found one row that matches the **`LEFT JOIN`** condition.

In most cases, the optimizer is even able to [use the smart trick](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html) that [Gordon suggested previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20977240/1446005):

> Consider the following subquery comparison:
>
> **`outer_expr IN (SELECT inner_expr FROM ... WHERE subquery_where)`**
>
> *[Provided that]* an appropriate equality *[is pushed down]* into the subquery's **`WHERE`** clause (...) the comparison is converted to this:
>
> **`EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE subquery_where AND outer_expr=inner_expr)`**

My point is, I would recommend using the for you are most used to, and only try other options if you ever encountered an *actual* performance issue here.

Comment: Note: I am not advising *not* to try to dig deeper into the question :) Just because it is *unnecessary* does not make the question less interesting.

Answer (score 2):

`joins` in MySQL are generally a good choice for performance.  It is possible that a `not exists` would be the fastest method in this case:

```
SELECT *
FROM Restaurant r
WHERE not exists (select 1 from Reservation rv where rv.restaurantId = r.id);
```

For optimal performance, you need an index on `Reservation(restaurantId)`.